Lattice operator - CFT primary field correspondence in chiral Ising CFT at the edge of 2D Ising topological order
It is known that the continuum field theoretic description of critical spin chains in 1-D is given by a 1+1D Conformal Field Theory (CFT). While mapping the CFT field operators to their corresponding lattice operators is difficult in general, the operator mapping for the critical 1D transverse field Ising model (TFIM) ($H = \sum_i Z_iZ_{i+1} + X_i$) and its companion c=1/2 Ising CFT is well understood. In particular, the Ising CFT has three primaries:

Identity field $\mathbb{I}$
Energy field $\epsilon$
Spin / order field $\sigma$

It is understood that the corresponding lattice operators for the critical TFIM are (see for example this answer) $\sigma \sim Z_i$, $\epsilon \sim Z_iZ_{i+1}-X_i$, and $\mathbb{I} \sim I$.
On the other hand, it is also known that for a 2-D Ising topological order, the edge is described by a chiral Ising (or free-Majorana fermion) CFT - for example, the edge states in the 'B-Phase' of Kitaev's Honeycomb model. I believe that the primary fields of the chiral CFT are the holomorphic (or antiholomorphic depending on the Chern number) components of the fields in the non-chiral theory, but I am not sure about this. My main question is: is there an understanding of the lattice operator - CFT primary field correspondence for the chiral Ising CFT? The details will likely depend on the underlying lattice theory - for concreteness, one can consider the B-phase of the spin-1/2 Honeycomb model.
